# Define an environment from tcbhighmath

Tags: macros, equations, environments, tcolorbox

Let's assume that I have defined very carefully the parameters of the `highlight math` style from the `tcolorbox` package.

I would like to define an environment

```
\newenvironment{equationbox}{%
    \begin{equation}%
    \tcbhighmath{% opening tcbhighmath
}{%
    }% closing tcbhighmath
    \end{equation}%
}
```

so that the result of using the environment would be:

```
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{%the environment contents%}
\end{equation}
```

The current version is obviously not working. I tried to replace the braces with `\bgroup \egroup` but it does not seem to work either. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `environ` package seems to be made for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{equationbox}{%
    \begin{equation}%
    \tcbhighmath{\BODY}
    \end{equation}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}%
    \tcbhighmath{E=mc^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equationbox}
E=mc^2
\end{equationbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]